# What is the difference between SMS Carrier & SMS Gateway?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

What is the difference between SMS Carrier & SMS Gateway.
Also what is the role of an aggregator in Gateway ?

Answer (score 3):

**SMS Carriers** are the wireless service providers like T-Mobile, AT&T, Verizon, etc. These companies use their own proprietary communication protocol.

We cannot connect two SMS centers if they do not support a common protocol. To deal with this, an **SMS Gateway** is placed between them. It will translate one protocol to another, and can be used by different wireless carriers to interconnect.

SMS Gateway software providers are referred to as **SMS Aggregators**. They have multiple agreements with the large mobile network providers to send and receive text messages through these networks' SMS centers.